# German Citizen Living in Germany, future possible job in Belgium Question on Retirement Insurance, Health Insurance, Taxes (oh boy)

Tags: germany, taxes, eu, belgium

I am currently living and working in Germany for a German company and I have 2 children. My wife has a part time job in Germany.

I received a job offer from a Belgian Company as either

1. a freelancer for 1 year
   or
2. a contract employee of 1 year (20€ less per day because they handle the paycheck paperwork)
   I would work in the office in Belgium a few days a month and the remaining days work remotely from Germany.

I am trying to understand the financial details of having a Belgian paycheck (with the appropriate deductions for Retirement, Health, Taxes) vs a Freelance contract.

The Belgian company is asking me for an decision but I do not have enough information to decide if I will even take the job. Some people I have asked have said there will be some very bad financial surprises and I should not take this job.

Health Insurance:
I contacted AOK and they told me I had 2 options.

1. As a Freelance contractor my monthly payment would be 900€ for my current coverage as a freelancer with freiwillige Insurance.
2. As an employee in Belgium and receive Belgium Insurance, cancelling AOK.
   So here the best option is probably
   #3) https://grenzinfo.eu/informationen/arbeiten-im-nachbarland/wohnen-deutschland-arbeiten-belgien/krankenversicherung/
   to transfer the children to my wife's AOK policy and for me to take the Belgium Insurance from the company as an employee. Would you agree ?

Kindergeld:
https://grenzinfo.eu/informationen/arbeiten-im-nachbarland/wohnen-deutschland-arbeiten-belgien/kind-und-familie/

Retirement Insurance:
https://grenzinfo.eu/informationen/arbeiten-im-nachbarland/wohnen-deutschland-arbeiten-belgien/rente/
I am currently contributing to the German Public Pension System.
With a Belgium paycheck I would start contributing to the Belgian system.
That is scaring me a lot.

Taxes:
I have not been able to find a Steuerberater that knows about this yet. Any suggestions ?
https://grenzinfo.eu/informationen/arbeiten-im-nachbarland/wohnen-deutschland-arbeiten-belgien/steuern/
I also tried https://www.icalculator.info/belgium.html but I think a tax advisor who has experience in this would be better.

Text chatting with a person at europa.eu produced a list of advisers but they are all bureaucrats working for Governments. I have emailed 3 from the list and none have answered yet.